# Решение задачи с циклом while

Tags: python

Нужно чтобы код считал пока m не будет равно 95, подскажите мою ошибку пожалуйста

```
m=0
i=0
k=0
n=0
while (m!=95):
    i=+0.01
    k=i+i/2
    n=k+k/2
    m=n+n/2
    print (m, i)
```

Задача была такая
Задуманное число при сложении этого же числа с его половиной, сложении полученного числа с его треть и сложении нового полученного числа с его четвертью дают 95

Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку в цикле

Comment: Во-первых, всюду складываются половины чисел, а не треть и не четверть.  Во-вторых, здесь нужен цикл, который считает результаты последовательного деления 95 на 5/4, 4/3 и 3/2, а не подбор числа с шагом в одну сотую.

Comment: Вообще задача математически решается в одно действие, без циклов. Если всё записать с натуральными дробями и потом сократить их, то получится `5/2*x=95`. Решив простенькое уравнение получаем `x=38`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша главная ошибка заключается в том, что при выполнении численных расчётов, ни в коем случае нельзя сравнивать на равенство числа с плавающей точкой. Только целые. Число с плавающей точкой - всегда **приближённое** значение. Точного равенства Вы не получите никогда и цикл надо переписать так:

```
i = 0
m = 0
while abs(m-95) > 0.0001:
    i = i+0.01
    k = i+i/2
    n = k+k/3
    m = n+n/4
    
print (m, i)
```

Тогда, после запуска программы, получим:

```
 95.00000000000253 38.00000000000101
```

С учётом ошибок округления, ответ 38:

38 + 19 = 57
57 + 19 = 76
76 + 19 = 95